# WKWebview Prevent updateUIView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When creating the `WKWebView` I pass the web page `URL` via `@Binding` `webPageURL`.

I also update the displayed website via `webPageURL`.

The problem here is that when I call a `NavigationLink` and navigate back from the `NavigationLink`, the `updateUIView` method is called and the `WKWebView` reloads the web page.

How do I prevent the `WKWebView` from calling the method `updateUIView` when I navigate back from the `NavigationLink`?

```
struct MainView:View {

    @State private var isActive = false
    @Binding var stateWebPageURL:String

    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            MyWKWebView(webPageURL:$stateWebPageURL)
            NavigationLink(destination: SecoundDestination(),isActive: $isActive) {
                Text("Do Something")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct MyWKWebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var webPageURL:String

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let pageURL = URL(string:webPageURL)
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: pageURL!)
        uiView.load(urlRequest)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero,configuration: webConfiguration)
        let pageURL = URL(string:webPageURL)
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: pageURL!)
        webView.load(urlRequest)
        return webView
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> ContentController {
        ContentController()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided code is not testable, so just by code reading, the idea is to make explicitly `MyWKWebView` equatable, as below

```
var body: some View {
    return VStack {
        MyWKWebView(webPageURL:$stateWebPageURL).equatable()   // << here !!
```

and

```
struct MyWKWebView: UIViewRepresentable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: MyWKWebView, rhs: MyWKWebView) -> Bool {
        lhs.webPageURL == rhs.webPageURL
    }

    // ... other your code
```

SwiftUI should not update equal views, so should work.